# Can't update data in Laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

Currently, I am working on a blog. But when I try to update a post, it's not getting updated and no error is reproduced.

What's wrong with the code? Anyone, please give me some suggestions to improvise my code. I want to understand what's the problem. So, anybody can explain in detail then I will really appreciate this thing.

**PostController code:-**

```
 public function update(Store $request,Post $post)
  {
        
    $data = $request->validated();
    $post = $post->update($data);
    return redirect('/index')->withMessage('successfully published');
  }
```

**View page code:-**

```
<form method="POST" action='/update'>
      @csrf
      <table class="table table table-striped table">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-form-label text-md-right">Title</label><br>
    <input required="required" placeholder="Enter title here" class="" type="text" name="title" class="" value="{{$data->title}}" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-form-label text-md-right">Description</label>
  </div>
    <div>
    <textarea name="description" class="" required>{{$data->description}}
    </textarea></div>
  <div>  
    <input type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-success" value="Update" required />
  </div>
</table>
</form>
```

**Route file code :-**

```
Route::get('posts/edit/{edit}',[PostController::class,'edit']);
    Route::post('/update',[PostController::class,'update']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Route `update` to this :

```
Route::post('posts/update',['as'=>'update','uses'=>'PostController@update']);
```

And in View Page

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('update') }}">
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but now it gives me->''ReflectionFunction::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given",  this type of error after clicking on update button

Comment: Actually, now I put some changes in my code. but now it creating a new record instead of editing the data.

Comment: Is it working now? or same issue persists?

Comment: yes now its working properly, thanks you so much for helping me